proper inclusions of differentiability classes
I’m studying real analysis and my professor proposed the following exercise
If $C^k$ is the set of functions f: I $\to$ R of class $C^k$ prove the inclusions and show that they are proper (inclusions)
$C^{\infty} \subset … \subset C^{n+1} \subset C^n \subset … \subset C^1 \subset C^0$
I tried proving this by induction over n. First I proved $C^1 \subset C^0$, which is obvious (I also noted that a continuous function is not necessarily differentiable). Then I supposed that the inclusions are valid for n, n-1, … 1, $0$, so now I have to show that $C^{n+1} \subset C^n$, but I’m stuck. I know that if a function is of class $C^{n+1}$, then f is n+1 times differentiable, then it is n times differentiable. How do I prove now that the nth derivative of f is continuous?

The inclusions follow immediately from the definition: If $f$ is $n + 1$ times continuously differentiable, $(f^{(n)})' = f^{(n + 1)}$ is continuous and so $f^{(n)}$ is continuously differentiable. The more interesting problem is to show that the inclusions are proper, that is, that for all $k \in {0, 1, 2, \ldots}$ there is a function $f \in C^k \setminus C^{k + 1}$.

If $f$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^{n+1}$, then $f$ is $(n+1)$ times differentiable, which implies that $f^{(n)}$ is differentiable and thus continuous. This means that $f$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^n$.
To prove that the inclusion is proper, take a continuous function which is not differentiable at some point and integrate it $n$ times.
